# Numpy segfault in Cython

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I have a Cython program that crashes eventually on a call to `np.asarray()` on a memory view of a packed `struct`.  I can run the exact same function over and over again with the same inputs using `%timeit` and it will eventually crash.

When I run it from `gdb`, the crash is an always an error on a call to `malloc` from `_buffer_info_new` on [line 472](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/buffer.c#L472). What could cause a crash in the `malloc` from a memory view?

I am using Continuum's Anaconda distribution, Python 2.7.10, Cython 0.23.3 and numpy 1.10.1

Comment: Well, one obvious explanation is that you're running out of memory - perhaps you have a memory leak that is consuming all available memory over successive function calls. You need to show your code, otherwise all we can do is speculate.

Comment: I wish I could.  It's a work problem and I am having an issue producing a toy example.

Comment: I "fixed" the segfault by over allocating the numpy array size to be bigger than the largest potential size.

Comment: Shooting in the dark here, but if you're using any of the numpy C-API you need to call ``numpy.import_array()`` (after ``cimport numpy``) at the top of the Cython file, or else you can get similar segfault issues. C-API functions look something like ``numpy.PyArray_SimpleNewFromData()``.

Comment: Thanks.  I had `numpy.import_array()`.  Any idea how to initialize an array from a memoryview using `numpy.PyArray_SimpleNewFromData()`:?

Comment: http://cython.org/docs/0.16/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#coercion-to-numpy

Comment: Jake's suggestion would only apply if you were already using the C-API in your code without calling `numpy.import_array()` first. There's no need need to use the likes of `numpy.PyArray_SimpleNewFromData()` if you already have a typed memoryview - [you ought to be able to coerce it to a numpy array using `np.asarray`](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#coercion-to-numpy). As for why that *doesn't* work in your case, all we can do is guess...

Comment: Unless you have a very good reason to use ``numpy.PyArray_SimpleNewFromData()``, I wouldn't suggest using it. I only bring it up because it's one possible thing that can lead to a SegFault, and you've given us very little to work with in this question :)